# Wordpress randomly returning 404

Tags: wordpress

I'm having a strange issue when I reload a page sequentially, sometimes it loads fine, but sometimes it loads with missing images/css, and sometimes it redirects to my site's 404 file. Below are 2 sequential curl commands which might be helpful.

For background, I've already cleared out the previous page slugs in the DB, and restored the .htaccss file. Any pointers are greatly appreciated!!

```
[my machine]:$ curl -s -D - [my url] -o /dev/null
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Date: Tue, 04 Mar 2014 21:44:50 GMT
Server: Apache
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.14
Content-Length: 6131
Connection: keep-alive

[my machine]:$ curl -s -D - [my url] -o /dev/null
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Date: Tue, 04 Mar 2014 21:44:51 GMT
Expires: Wed, 11 Jan 1984 05:00:00 GMT
Last-Modified: Tue, 04 Mar 2014 21:44:51 GMT
Pragma: no-cache
Server: Apache
X-Pingback: http://promotions.glamour.com/xmlrpc.php
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.14
transfer-encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive
```

Comment: What's in the server logs?

Comment: Unfortunately this is on a shared corporate server so I can't publish them. However the administrator tells me there are no errors.

Comment: any custom rewrite rules that were changes in plugin / themes recently ?

Comment: Hi @ObmerkKronen - no, there was nothing modified there. I think the issue is that Wordpress is somehow interfering with directories/images in my site root. For example, when I open /directory/images/image.jpg in a web browser and refresh a few times, sometimes the image loads, but sometimes it goes to my WP theme's 404 page. Can this help you diagnose a fix?

Answer (score 4):

**Wordpress randomly returning 404**

I had a similar problem and I discovered the fix. Leaving this for whoever may come to this page as I did in search of a solution.

Turned out that it was because some plug-ins were causing a spike in memory consumption and the shared hosting (Dreamhost) was killing requests that took too much memory, and returned a 404 error. In my log files I was seeing "Premature end of script headers".

I disabled all non-critical plug-ins and not only have the random 404s stopped, but the site is loading much faster overall.

Comment: I am on Dreamhost too and experience this often. A site that I have many plugins on has more 404 than other simpler sites.

I often suspected this - time to move away from them I guess. Thanks for your post.

Comment: What was the plugin?

Comment: I don't recall, but you can use https://wordpress.org/plugins/query-monitor/ to help narrow down which one it is.

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out the solution had nothing to do with Wordpress.

Long story short - a second duplicate server had been quietly set up to handle large traffic spikes, and our build scripts knew nothing about that new server and weren't deploying to it.

Ahh the joys of troubleshooting at a large company...